# Find top parent of child, multiple levels

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ENTRY TABLE
 __________________
| ID |  PARENT_ID  |
| 1  |    null     |
| 2  |     1       |
| 3  |     2       |
| 4  |    null     |
| 5  |     4       |
| 6  |     5       |
...
```

I make copies of the entries in some cases and they are conneted by parent ID.

Each entry can have one copy:

```
THIS WONT HAPPEN
 __________________
| ID |  PARENT_ID  |
| 1  |    null     |
| 2  |     1       |
| 3  |     1       |
...
```

Sometimes I need to take a copy and query for it's top level parent. I need to find the top parent entries for all the entries I search for.

For example, if I query for the parents of ID 6 and 3, I would get ID 4 and 1.
If I query for the parents of ID 5 and 2, I would get ID 4 and 1.
But also If I query for ID 5 and 1, it should return ID 4 and 1 because the entry ID 1 is already the top parent itself.

I don't know where to begin since I don't know how to recursively query in such case.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I know that the query below will just return the child elemements (ID 6 and 3), but I don't know where to go from here honestly.

I am using OracleSQL by the way.

```
SELECT * FROM entry WHERE id IN (6, 3);
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html).

Comment: You are dealing with a hierarchy, and specifically in your case with a collection of very special trees, where each node has at most one child. You are looking for the "root" of a tree, given an arbitrary "node"; which means you need to "traverse" from bottom to top, rather than top to bottom. If all this terminology is unfamiliar to you, you should first read a little about "directed trees" to learn about ancestors and descendants, roots and leaves, etc. Then using the `CONNECT BY` hierarchical clause will actually be pretty obvious. Can't skip the basics though.

Comment: Looking into it thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query and `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`.

Either starting at the root of the hierarchy and working down:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id) AS root_id
FROM   entry
WHERE  id IN (6, 3)
START WITH parent_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id;
```

Or, from the entry back up to the root:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(id) AS id,
       id AS root_id
FROM   entry
WHERE  parent_id IS NULL
START WITH id IN (6, 3)
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entry( id, parent_id ) AS
SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 6 FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> | ID | ROOT_ID |
> | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 1 |
> | 6 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a4ee39e30707104bb256336bd77f50f)*

Comment: Starting from the roots doesn't make a lot of sense - why inspect trees (in the forest) that don't contain the required nodes to begin with? The only logical approach is to start from the nodes themselves and work "upwards" to find the roots (which are actually "leaves" when traversing in the upward direction).

Comment: @mathguy For the OP's data where there are no branches and they are selecting one item per tree then it doesn't make much difference; however, in the general case where is a forest of branching trees then I'd agree with you and start with the items and work back up to the root of the trees (I just happened to write the other version first and edited the other version in later when I thought it was more appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive CTE to walk the graph and find the initial parent. For example:

```
with
n (starting_id, current_id, parent_id, v) as (
  select id, id, parent_id, 0 from entry where id in (6, 3)
 union all
  select n.starting_id, e.id, e.parent_id, n.v - 1
  from n
  join entry e on e.id = n.parent_id
)
select starting_id, current_id as initial_id
from (
  select n.*, row_number() over(partition by starting_id order by v) as rn
  from n
) x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
 STARTING_ID  INITIAL_ID 
 ------------ ----------
 3            1         
 6            4
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81d2ae02d0006ecdbfb87de91b36d857).

Comment: You don't need to use `ROW_NUMBER`, just filter on `WHERE parent_id IS NULL` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87a35abc8ab29e2d59d8840b448d4a11)

Comment: @MT0 Sigh. I think I need a coffee.

Comment: Also, if speed is important, recursive CTE should only be used when hierarchical queries are not possible or are very complicated (and also for SQL dialects that, unlike Oracle, don't have hierarchical queries; `connect by` is not in the SQL standard, it is proprietary to Oracle).